# Binding buttons to Alt keypresses?

Tags: tkinter

I've got a simple Tkinter application I've written, with a few buttons at the bottom of a form. My goal is to follow the standard convention of underlining a letter on the button, and binding an action for that letter with the Alt key (ie: Alt-s for "_S_ave").

I've tried making a root window binding to "Alt-s", "Alt-KeyPress-s", and "Mod1-s", and none seem to work reliably. They sometimes fire, but even though I have "return break" on my event function the "s" letter is propagating to the entry widget.

I believe this is an issue with Linux/X11 and Mod1 vs Alt handling because Control key bindings work consistently. I haven't been able to locate any best practices for working around the issue, thus my appeal here.

Can someone share how to get an Alt key binding working in Linux/X11?

** Updated with a sample

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        e = Entry(self.root)
        e.grid(column=0,row=0)
        b = Button(self.root, text="Save", underline = 0)
        b.grid(column=0,row=1)
        root.bind("<Alt-s>",self.save)
        e.focus()

    def save(self,event=None):
        print("Hey, you pressed Alt-s!")
        return "break"

root = Tk()
App = GUI(root)
print("At this point, pressing Alt-s places the s string in the entry widget, and doesn't trigger")
root.mainloop()
```

** Update 2

I've had a few reviewers let me know this works on their system, even Linux. Perhaps there's a problem with my tiling wm or other configuration for X11, however I've had no problems using Alt with any other X11 GUI apps.

I'm open to suggestions on how to troubleshoot this.

** Update 3

I've been reviewing the behavior with xmodmap, and it appears that when I assign Alt_R the Tk keybindings stop working. The events reported by xev match verbatim, and yet Tk's behavior changes. Still digging.

** Update 4

Mr. Lange on the Tkinter list found a link that helps explain similar behavior, at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=58145 .

I've made that change to my xmodmap, and now Alt works as expected. I can't explain why binding Alt_R to mod4 would effect Alt_L, or why it would only effect Tk applications.

Thanks.

Comment: How about a snippet we can try where alt is not working for?

Comment: I thought I'd point out I'm using the tiling WM AwesomeWM, and have right mod xmodmapped to something else but the left is unmodified. Emacs, Firefox, Openoffice, and other GUI apps read Alt-key normally.

Comment: You'r code works as intended for me in windows XP with python 2.7.1. Sorry I can't help any more, I don't have a linux machine on hand. :/ good luck.

Comment: I appreciate the help so far. Like I said, I believe this is related to Linux's handling of Alt/mod.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, +1 for a concise problem description and updates.

Comment: No idea, I appreciate the input though. I'm trying to get to the bottom of the issue and leave a record for the next person. I thought this was supposed to be trivial, and I'm rather surprised at the lack of consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that modifying Alt_R to bind it to the Windows key (Mod4) was the root cause of the problem. I believe that made Alt_L work as Mod1 though it was explicitly not modified in xmodmap. Therefor it must have broken some implied behavior, but only for Tk apps.

From the Arch BBS link modifying the Alt_R keycode to trigger Super_L resolved the behavior. So now Alt_R functions as the Windows key, but Tk doesn't notice any changes with Alt_L.

Root bindings for Alt now work appropriately without double binding, because Entry widgets ignore Alt keypresses by default. With proper Alt behavior, not only are the Alt key bindings working, but the return break behavior isn't required either.

I did not see default ignore bindings for Mod1 keys in any widget, and if Alt_L suddenly decided to present Mod1 that does explain the behavior where Mod1 bindings would fire, but a double binding was required to prevent the Entry widget from getting the key.

~/.Xmodmap for reference:

```
! ISO_Level3_Shift is what xev reports for my right Alt key
! mod4 is the Windows key modifier, and tied to WM operations

! Trying a different approach documented at
! https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=58145
keycode 108 = Super_L
remove mod1 = Super_L
```

What a messy problem, altering an undocumented implied behavior through an indirect change...

Comment: Another potential issue is if you are using objects for your Tk app, for instance creating your own root class and inheriting from Tk if you fail to call the parent class __init__, Tk works but none of the bindings do. In my case I setup an incorrect super() call, just a friendly reminder.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this will work differently on linux, but i figured i'd give this answer a shot because it's been a couple days with no reply.

I'm not sure if this is the syntax you are using or not, but instead of `return break` try `return ("break")`

as for the alt problem, maybe try something like:

```py
from Tkinter import *
    
class GUI:
    def __init__(self,root):    
        self.alt = False
        e = Entry(root)
        e.pack()
        e.focus()
        root.bind("<Alt_L>",self.AltOn)
        root.bind("<KeyRelease-Alt_L>",self.AltOff)
        root.bind("<s>",self._s)

    def AltOn(self,event): self.alt=True
    def AltOff(self,event): self.alt=False
    def _s(self,event):
        if self.alt:
            #whatever you want to do with alt+s
            print "ALT S"
            return ("break")

root = Tk()
App = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: The description for bind is:

```
    FUNC will be called if the event sequence occurs with an
    instance of Event as argument. If the return value of FUNC is
    "break" no further bound function is invoked.
```

So i'm really not sure why break isn't working for you.. sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Alt-s seemed to work reliably, but break didn't prevent the "s" from going into the entry widget. I tried Python 2.6.6 and 3.2 (with minor tweaks so it would run).

Comment: @Symon: The reason why break isn't working is that the bindings on the widget and the widget class fire before bindings to the root window or to "all". Thus, the "break" comes too late in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Revised answer:

I was able to get your example to work and not populate the entry box by adding a second    binding to the entry (Ubuntu 10.04):

```
e.bind("<Alt-s>",self.save)
```

And on the OSX Lion system (same keyboard) with:

```
e.bind("<Option-s>",self.save)
```

xmodmap (Ubuntu 10.04):

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):    
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 10.02 myself, and tried it with Python 2.6.6 and 3.2 (with minor syntax fixes). It didn't trigger on Alt-f.

Comment: In my attempt, as long as the root window was selected, it triggers fine.  I'm checking my python/tkinter/tcl versions...

Comment: I use sloppy focus, but the window was selected. Other GUI apps like Firefox work fine when I trigger their menus with Alt-key.

Comment: I checked, my 2.6.6 installation in Ubuntu matches yours. The problem here is I've been unable to figure out *why* the alt key isn't working. Your example is fine... Its similar to what I've tried.

Comment: Mind posting the output of xmodmap?

Comment: xmodmap output has been posted.

Comment: Adding your extra binding to the entry widget works, but only if both are "Mod1-s", not "Alt-s". Can you explain why you have to bind twice, or why Mod1 is honored with Alt isn't? My modmap is the same as yours except having Alt_R on mod4.

Comment: What happens if you use the default mapping? (btw on OSX it would still populate the entry widget, until I added the second binding, so sounds like it was working the same way...)

Comment: I reset the mappings via setxkbmap, and tried it. I experienced the same result: Mod1 is honored, Alt is not. The "s" passes through to the entry widget unless I bind the mapping to the entry widget as well as root. That's confusing, because I had read that binding it to root should be enough with the break.

Comment: @Demosthenex: you have to bind twice because the binding on the root window is fired _after_ the default entry widget bindings. Because of that, returning "break" comes too late because the character has already been inserted. For more information read up on bind tags. By the way, there are other ways to solve this without binding twice, but it requires changing the bind tags for all your widgets which is usually more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: That makes sense, so then can you provide any insight on why Mod1 works but not Alt?